# How to position table-cell in a box-element

Tags: html, css, margin, tablecell, box-sizing

I made a Chessboard using HTML and CSS for an assignment. Now I need to position this Chessboard inside the box element so the margin left/right will be the same and the header element is shown. I tried using margin: auto; but this didn't work Neither did changing the box-sizing to content-box or border-box.

I am not allowed to use line-height to vertical align so I need display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle. Nor can I use justify-content if that would help. It should be done with basic HTML and CSS.

How can I get the Chessboard to position correctly like the image?

[image: Example of how it should look like]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ron1986/7r6h2wqn/4/)

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="chessboardbox">
        <h2>Chessboard</h2>
            <table class="chessboard">
                <tr class="chessboard">
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9820;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9822;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9821;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9819;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9818;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9821;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9822;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9820;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="chessboard">
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="chessboard">
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="chessboard">
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="chessboard">
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="chessboard">
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                    <td class="chessboard"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="chessboard">
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="chessboard">
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9814;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9816;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9815;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9813;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9812;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9815;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9816;</td>
                    <td class="chessboard">&#9814;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    .chessboardbox {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid silver;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

table.chessboard {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 48px auto;
    background: #999;
    border: 5px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 0 40px black;
}
td.chessboard {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size:50px;
}

tr.chessboard {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

tr.chessboard:nth-child(odd) td.chessboard:nth-child(even),
tr.chessboard:nth-child(even) td.chessboard:nth-child(odd) {
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the entire `display:table-cell;` property from `table.chessboard{}`.  I also centered the `h2` text for you.  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/sonp2h7a/)

```css
.chessboardbox {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.chessboardbox>h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

table.chessboard {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 48px auto;
  background: #999;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 0 40px black;
}

td.chessboard {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

tr.chessboard {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr.chessboard:nth-child(odd) td.chessboard:nth-child(even),
tr.chessboard:nth-child(even) td.chessboard:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="chessboardbox">
      <h2>Chessboard</h2>
      <table class="chessboard">
        <tr class="chessboard">
          <td class="chessboard">&#9820;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9822;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9821;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9819;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9818;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9821;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9822;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9820;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chessboard">
          <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chessboard">
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chessboard">
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chessboard">
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chessboard">
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
          <td class="chessboard"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chessboard">
          <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="chessboard">
          <td class="chessboard">&#9814;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9816;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9815;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9813;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9812;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9815;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9816;</td>
          <td class="chessboard">&#9814;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add two div tags on the table tag with chessboard class to help centering the chessboard:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="chessboardbox">
        <h2 class="title">Chessboard</h2>
        <!-- ADDED HERE -->
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="board">
          <table class="chessboard">
            <tr class="chessboard">
                <td class="chessboard">&#9820;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9822;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9821;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9819;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9818;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9821;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9822;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9820;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="chessboard">
                <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9823;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="chessboard">
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="chessboard">
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="chessboard">
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="chessboard">
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
                <td class="chessboard"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="chessboard">
                <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9817;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="chessboard">
                <td class="chessboard">&#9814;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9816;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9815;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9813;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9812;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9815;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9816;</td>
                <td class="chessboard">&#9814;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the css elements that I have added:

ADDED:

```
.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  padding: 5% 20%;
}

.board {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

CHANGED:

```
.chessboardbox {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  display: block;
}
```